# Putting two plots with different axes into one with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have two plots in Matplotlib that I would like to merge. They have different axes and scales. Here is the code for each of them.
Electrical Power Plot:

```
    #Case Study: Curtailment
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

load = [0, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 665, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500,0,2500, 2366, 250, 250, 373, 2500,0, 2500, 0, 2500,250, 0]    
hours = list(range(25)) # [0, 1, 2, ... 22, 23, 24]
labels = [f'{h:02d}:00' for h in hours] # ["00:00", "01:00", ... "23:00", "24:00"]

fig = plt.figure(linewidth=1, figsize=(9, 5))
ax = plt.gca()


ax.plot(hours, load, color="goldenrod",drawstyle="steps-post",  linewidth=3) # <- drawstyle argument.
ax.set_xlabel("Time of day", fontsize=14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_ylabel("Electrical power in W", fontsize=14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_xlim(0, 24)
ax.set_ylim(0, 3000)    
plt.xticks(hours, labels=labels, rotation=90)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=.4)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
# (Optional) ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.03, 1.15), fontsize = 14, ncol=3)
plt.tight_layout() # This must be called last, after all elements (plot and legend) are ready.
plt.savefig('CS_Curtailment_ElectricalLoad.png', edgecolor='black', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Temperature Plot:

```
#Case Study: Curtailment
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

temperature = [
21.00,
21.02,
20.96,
20.85,
20.68,
20.46,
20.40,
20.56,
20.77,
21.06,
21.41,
21.79,
21.10,
21.57,
22.00,
21.47,
20.92,
20.46,
20.92,
20.31,
20.77,
20.35,
20.90,
21.00,
21.00
]    
hours = list(range(25)) # [0, 1, 2, ... 22, 23, 24]
labels = [f'{h:02d}:00' for h in hours] # ["00:00", "01:00", ... "23:00", "24:00"]

fig = plt.figure(linewidth=1, figsize=(9, 5))
ax = plt.gca()


ax.plot(hours, temperature, color="red",  linewidth=3) # <- drawstyle argument.
ax.set_xlabel("Time of day", fontsize=14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_ylabel("Temperature in °C", fontsize=14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_xlim(0, 24)
ax.set_ylim(20, 22.5)    
plt.xticks(hours, labels=labels, rotation=90)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=.4)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
# (Optional) ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.03, 1.15), fontsize = 14, ncol=3)
plt.tight_layout() # This must be called last, after all elements (plot and legend) are ready.
plt.savefig('CS_Curtailment_Temperature.png', edgecolor='black', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

I would like to have the electrical power axis on the left (first plot) and the temperature axis on the right (second plot). Of course the two plots have similar x-axis values.
Can you do this with Matplotlib?

I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done in matplotlib to do so, first generate the first `ax` (electrical power) and then instantiate the second axes

```
ax.plot(hours, load, color="goldenrod",drawstyle="steps-post",  linewidth=3)
# ... 

#generate the second instance
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(hours, temperature, color="red",  linewidth=3)
# ... set additional configuration for ax2
```

Both axes will share the same `x-axes` and the same `fig`, so make sure that before showing the plot to tight the layout, otherwise y-label might be clipped.

```
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**

To handle both axes at the same time, you need to use the figure object, so use it to save them to a `png` and set the legend. `legend()` method need to receive the `labels` which you can set manually of on each `ax.plot( ..., label='<label>')`

1. get the current figure before `plt.show()`
2. Set the legend using the figure object.
3. Save the image using the figure object.
4. Show the image.

The code:

```
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.15, 1.07), fontsize=14, ncol=3)
fig.savefig('CS_Curtailment_CombinedDiagram.png',
        edgecolor='black', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer jcaliz. Basically the plot looks good on Jupyther Notebooks. Unfortunately there are still two problems: 1) When I want to save the file with the command 'plt.savefig('CS_Curtailment_CombinedDiagram.png', edgecolor='black', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')' only an empty figure is stored. 2) I would also like to add a legend at the upper rim of the plot. When I use the command 'ax2.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.15, 1.07), fontsize = 14, ncol=3)' I get an error message "No handles with labels found to put in legend."

Comment: Thanks jcaliz for your answer. Now the picture can be saved. However regarding the legend I still get the same error message "No handles with labels found to put in legend.
". I just copied and pasted your code from the EDIT section into my code.

Comment: You need to set the labels on each plot, check you have `label` parameter in each `ax.plot`